# Nativescript webview set permission for mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: webview, permissions, webrtc, nativescript

I am using Nativescript webview to run my web-app. But have problem when trying to do:

```
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: false
    }).then(function (stream) {
```

Anybody know how to set permission for WEBRTC related functions?

Thanks a lot!

Note:

1. it's for android and I have search for few hours but it seems no complete explanation about requesting permission, unlike for android studio (like this one: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings).
2. the web-app is running well under google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works, but I am using standard java (android studio without the IDE), the most important parts are:

1. use webchromeclient.
2. set permission: android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE.
3. manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true"/>
```